# How to drag and drop user created rectangles on canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

Very new to WPF and C# and I am trying to build a very primitive image editor. The user can currently create a rectangle of any size with the left mouse button and delete any rectangle with the right mouse button. I am trying to add more functionality by allowing the rectangles to be dragged and dropped however I cannot seem to find a good solution for it. Most of the answers I have seen are dealing with a hard-coded custom rectangle in the canvas itself while my case deals with a user-generated one.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppCaseGuard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppCaseGuard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_LeftMouseButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="Canvas_RightMouseButtonDown" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"  Background="Transparent">
        
        <Button x:Name="btnOpen" Content="Select Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="367,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Image x:Name="imagePicture"/>
    </Canvas>
    
    
</Window>
```

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAppCaseGuard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Uri fileUri = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName);
                imagePicture.Source = new BitmapImage(fileUri);
            }
        }

        private Point startPoint;
        private Rectangle rect;

        private void Canvas_LeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

            rect = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue
            };
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect,startPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect,startPoint.Y);
            canvas.Children.Add(rect);

            
            
        }

        private void Canvas_RightMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
            {
                Rectangle activeRect = (Rectangle)e.OriginalSource;
                canvas.Children.Remove(activeRect);
            }
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released || rect == null)
                return;

            var pos = e.GetPosition (canvas);
            var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
            var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);
            var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
            var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

            rect.Width = w;
            rect.Height = h;

            Canvas.SetLeft (rect,x);
            Canvas.SetTop (rect,y);
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            rect = null;
        }

       



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
public void MakeDraggable(FrameworkElement dragObject, Canvas canvas)
    {
        bool isDragging = false;
        double clickPosition_X = 0;
        double clickPosition_Y = 0;

        dragObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Control_MouseLeftButtonDown);
        dragObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Control_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        dragObject.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseMove);

        void Control_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = true;
            var p = e.GetPosition(dragObject);
            clickPosition_X = p.X;
            clickPosition_Y = p.Y;
            dragObject.CaptureMouse();
        }

        void Control_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            dragObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        void Control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDragging)
            {
                Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(dragObject.Parent as Canvas);
                dragObject.Margin = new Thickness(currentPosition.X - clickPosition_X, currentPosition.Y - clickPosition_Y, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
MakeDraggable(rectangle, canvas);
```